# Configure apache traffic server over SSL

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

I'm trying to configure a SSL reverse proxy using Apache traffic server on Ubuntu 14.04

I have a tomcat server (spring boot) on port 8443 (https) and Apache traffic server on port 443

I followed all the SSL configuration steps mentioned in Administration page :

https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/5.3.x/admin/security-options.en.html

And added the below mapping in remap.config

```
map https://localhost:443/ https://localhost:8443/
```

I added the following line in ssl_multicert.config

```
ssl_cert_name=cert.public.pem
```

Also Updated the following config in records.config

```
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 443
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.cert.path STRING /etc/trafficserver
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.private_key.path STRING /etc/trafficserver
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.cert.path STRING /etc/trafficserver
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.cert.filename STRING cert.public.pem
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.private_key.path STRING /etc/trafficserver
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.client.private_key.filename STRING key.private.pem
```

But I always get the below response on browser:

This site can’t provide a secure connection

localhost sent an invalid response.

However the reverse proxy works if tomcat server in on port 8090 (http)
and following mapping is added

```
map http://localhost:443/ http://localhost:8090/
```

So how do I configure traffic server to support SSL ??

Comment: Can you provide your ssl virtualhost code?

Comment: @NitinDhomse : What code are you talking about? Configuration in *.config files?

Comment: Yes, the code written in your conf file for ssl and proxy i.e virtualhost.

Comment: @NitinDhomse :  I have added the config code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work when I placed :ssl to the end of 443 in records.config

```
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 80 80:ipv6 443:ssl
```